# Is there a hook or plugin to exclude certain product-tags from a woocommerce coupon?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I need to exclude a product tag from a woocommerce coupon.

I've tried to search Google for an applicable plugin, but came up empty.

Ideally, a solution would be a plugin that adds a custom field to the coupon post type. However, I'll settle for hard coding through a hook/filter.

Comment: Hello! Please note that asking for third-party-resources is considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a filter you can use to accomplish this **woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product**.

It accepts 4 parameters, valid, the product, the coupon and values. It's called from **class-wc-coupon.php** around line 860 in version 3 or so. It should return a boolean (**true/false**).

Note that the code below is incomplete and untested, and is for example purposes only.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product', 'exclude_product_from_coupon_by_tag', 12, 4);
function exclude_product_from_coupon_by_tag($valid, $product, $coupon, $values ){
    
    //Check if product has tag/s
    $valid = has_term('INSERT_TERM_HERE', 'product_tag', $product);

    return $valid;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you; that should work. I was having a hard time finding that specific filter.

Comment: I guess that doesn't work anymore... I'm receiving error on each product I'm trying to apply the coupon code on.

Comment: @YotamDahan it's still there unchanged in latest WC (5.4.1). I'm guessing whatever you're checking in your callback is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

As Seb Toombs said you must use **woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product** filter to check product validation by tag. If the validation returns you an error you must change the **$product** with **$product->get_id()**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product', 'exclude_product_from_coupon_by_tag', 12, 4);
function exclude_product_from_coupon_by_tag($valid, $product, $coupon, $values ){
    
    //Check if product has tag/s
    $valid = has_term('INSERT_TERM_HERE', 'product_tag', $product->get_id());

    return $valid;
}
```